# Save radiougroup pressed

Tags: java, android, button, save

Пишу приложение для андроид,которое состоит из двух Активити,на первой кнопки radiobutton на которые я ссылаюсь через radiogroup,при выборе передаётся информация на второе активити,возникла проблема сохранения выбора кнопки на первой активити,допустим пользователь выбрал второй вариант,потом закрыл или вернулся обратно на первое активити а выбор на кнопке не сохранён,пытался методами с форума,но ни один не сохраняет выбор,есть какой нибудь простой и рабочий код,который сохранит состояние в radiogroup?
Код:

```
    Intent intent;

String name;

RadioGroup radioGroup;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    intent = new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                name =getResources().getResourceEntryName(checkedId);
                intent.putExtra("sample",name);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }
});  }}
```

Comment: вам нужны методы onSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState. записываете в бандл параметр, какой радиобатн был чекнут в onSave и в onRestore восстанавливаете состояние

Comment: У меня прописан только radiogroup и через него определяется radiobutton,можно это как то связать и как это в виде кода?

Comment: Используйте `SharedPreferences`, при клике сохраняете состояние кнопки, а в `onCreate` получаете последнее состояние кликнутой кнопки из `RadioGroup`.

Comment: А можно пример кода,на словах я тоже знаю эти методы,но на практике результат нулевой